# How can I connect the line graph points one by one using lines function in R?

Tags: r, graph, line

My excel data is like this:

```
Date        Total Bilirubin(umol/l)
10/18/2015  336.9
10/21/2015  352.7
10/24/2015  330.4
10/27/2015  310.2
10/30/2015  390.3
11/2/2015   378.3
11/5/2015   435.8
11/8/2015   449.3
11/11/2015  460.7
11/14/2015  385.3
11/17/2015  350.7
11/20/2015  278.6
11/23/2015  252.1
11/26/2015  180.8
11/29/2015  159.4
12/2/2015   105.5
12/5/2015   83.2
12/8/2015   64.4
12/11/2015  60.8
```

I use R to draw a line graph like this:

```
dat<-read.xlsx("/Users/user/Research/Obstructive Jaundice/liuxuebin bilirubin.xlsx",sheetName = "liuxuebin_bilirubin")
dat$Date<-factor(dat$Date)

lines(dat$Date,dat$Total.Bilirubin.umol.l.,type="b",lwd=1.5,lty=3,col="red",pch=16)
```

I get the graph like this:
[image]

I want to connect the dots one by one to see the bilirubin changing trend. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Try to not convert `dat$Date` to `factor`, and sort by Date `library(dplyr); dat %>% arrange(dat, Date)`

Comment: It doesn't work. The output graph is the same as the one in the post. What can I do? I just want to see the changing trend of bilirubin level with time.

Comment: Try converting the date column to a Date object `dat$Date<-as.Date(dat$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")  `

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you very much. But it doesn't work too. I think I have used the wrong function. But I don't know which function to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is the Date column is being imported as a factor variable. If that is the case then convert the column to a character object and then to a Date object.  Then the plot function should work well.

```
dat<-read.table(text="Date        Total.Bilirubin(umol/l)
10/18/2015  336.9
                 10/21/2015  352.7
                 10/24/2015  330.4
                 10/27/2015  310.2
                 10/30/2015  390.3
                 11/2/2015   378.3
                 11/5/2015   435.8
                 11/8/2015   449.3
                 11/11/2015  460.7
                 11/14/2015  385.3
                 11/17/2015  350.7
                 11/20/2015  278.6
                 11/23/2015  252.1
                 11/26/2015  180.8
                 11/29/2015  159.4
                 12/2/2015   105.5
                 12/5/2015   83.2
                 12/8/2015   64.4
                 12/11/2015  60.8", header=TRUE)

#convert dat$Date from a factor to a Date object
dat$Date<-as.Date(as.character(dat$Date), format="%m/%d/%Y") 
#plot image
plot(dat$Date,dat$Total.Bilirubin.umol.l.,type="b",lwd=1.5,lty=3,col="red",pch=16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much